# В каком падеже стоит числительное в сочетании с сущ. "на сумму"?

Tags: морфология

Пример: "Осуществлена покупка оборудования на сумму 2000 рублей". А если число написать словами? "...на сумму две тысячи рублей" или "...на сумму двух тысяч рублей" - как все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно на сумму две тысячи рублей.
Падеж - винительный: "На **какую** сумму?"

Почему вдруг вы усомнились и рассматриваете возможность родительного ([нет] какой суммы? - двух тысяч рублей) - не очень понятно, поэтому даже не комментирую.